# next js gives error when trying to push state to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to push to firebase a date that I get from https://react-schedule-meeting.netlify.app/, pass it to a state and push the state  as such :
calendar :

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState()

                  <ScheduleMeeting
                    primaryColor={calendarPrimary}
                    eventDurationInMinutes={30}
                    borderRadius={calendarRadius}
                    startTimeListStyle={timeStyle}
                    selectedDateMonthTitleFormatString="cccc, LLLL do"
                    availableTimeslots={timestamps}
                    onStartTimeSelect={setDate}
                  />
```

push to firebase :

```
  const handleCreate = () => {
    const db = getFirestore(app)
    if (router.query.calendar) {
      console.log('date ', date)
      setDoc(doc(db, 'links', router.query.calendar, 'meetings', meetingname), {
        timeValue: timeValue,
        name: meetingname,
        email: meetingemail,
        date: date
      }).then(notify)
    }
  }
```

get data from firebase

```
        if (docSnap.exists()) {

          setSchedule(docSnap.data())
          console.log(docSnap.data()['schedule'])
          for (var i in docSnap.data()['schedule']) {
            setTimestamps((array) => [...array, { startTime: new Date(docSnap.data()['schedule'][0]['start']['seconds'] * 1000), endTime: new Date(docSnap.data()['schedule'][0]['end']['seconds'] * 1000) }]);

          }
        }
```

listen for changes (this is a modal form )

```
  useEffect(() =>{
    if(date){
    setOpened(true)
    }
  }, [date])
```

My problem is : if I get the dates (used by the calendar to show schedule and availability)  from firebase as timestamps and push them to the calendar I get the following error :
[image]

And If i get the dates as shown in the calendar example ( https://react-schedule-meeting.netlify.app/docs/quick-start) everything works and the date state is not undefined .
I have consoled.log everything and from my form only the date state returns undefined.

Comment: We can't see all the code we need to here. Can you share where these vars come from? `timeValue: timeValue,
        name: meetingname,
        email: meetingemail,
        date: date`

Comment: @adsy as I said the problem is with the date var, which is specified where it comes from ,the others are not important, there are just a few fields that have a state which changes when users inputs something

Comment: I understand, but whilst it seems unimportant it's also harder for answerers to get an understanding of the code when it's split into chunks like this since it means we can't see the scoping of all the vars and understand the flow of data through the component and between user interactions. This is especially important here where the order of the calls and nature of the effects is highly important. I assume `const [date, setDate] = useState()` is where `date` comes from for the `setDoc` call, but its unclear. If you post the whole component or close to it I can help better :).